# Taking action on app start up based on Push Notification

Tags: ios

I have push notifications enabled for my app and I detect whether the app is opened from a push notification or not on `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

I want to take action based on the push notification that the user has opened the app from. So for example if the notification says "Someone has added you to their friends", opening the app from that notification would take the user to that other user's profile.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

on application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method;

```
NSDictionary *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
if (notification) {
    // do something with notification
}
```

Comment: I already do this, but how can I check the type of the notification? I want to be able to send the user to different section in the app based on the notification they get. Can I add my own keys to the aps dictionary to be able to read them when the app is launched?

Comment: yes, you can add any keys you want to your notification and read them here easily. to see it clearly, just use NSLog(@"Notification:%@", notification);

Comment: but you should put your custom keys on root of your payload, not in 'aps' key. see here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1